# Treat generic instance of TypeA as generic instance of SuperclassOfTypeA

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have a `var responders = [String:[UIResponder]]()` (read: `Dictionary` with `String`s as keys and `Array`s of `UIResponder`s as values).

Can I treat a `[String:[UIView]]` as if it's a `[String:[UIResponder]]`?

Wouldn't it be the same as casting a `UIView` to `UIResponder`?

```
import UIKit

var responders = [String:[UIResponder]]()

var views = [String:[UIView]]()

responders = views // Error: 'UIView' is not identical to 'UIResponder'

responders = views as [String:[UIResponder]] // Error: 'UIView' is not identical to 'UIResponder'
```

It's even weirder that using just an `[UIResponder]` (read: `Array` of `UIResponders`) works just fine.

```
import UIKit

var responders = [UIResponder]()

var views = [UIView]()

responders = views // No error

responders = views as [UIResponder] // No error
```

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Note: In many languages that `Array<Child>` is not subtype of `Array<Parent>`

Comment: This looks like it might be a bug; I would recommend posting in [the developer forums](http://devforums.apple.com) and [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Using `[String:UIResponder]` and `[String:UIView]` also works just fine. However, array-of-arrays (i.e., `[[UIResponder]]`, etc) does not work. It appears that doubly nesting the genericized type breaks casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force the cast by using `reinterpretCast`:

```
import UIKit

var responders = [String:[UIResponder]]()

var views = [String:[UIView]]()

responders = reinterpretCast(views)
```

Although by doing this, you are taking on the responsibility of ensuring that the cast is valid.